# REST API Documentation in html using Swagger - file paths.html has not links, grouped by controllers api

Tags: java, rest, swagger

I'm trying to generate REST API Documentation using Swagger, and I want to get the documentation in HTML.

I use following command:

```
Swagger2MarkupConverter.from("http://localhost:9090/api-docs")
                .build()
                .intoFolder("docs/apidoc/generated");`
```

and I got my documentation in asciidoc files: `definition.adoc`, `overview.adoc`, `paths.adoc`.

Then, I use `asciidoctor-gradle-plugin` and run Gradle task `asciidoctor`:

```
ext {
    sourceDirGeneratedDocumentation = file('docs/apidoc/generated')
    outputDirGeneratedDocumentation = file('docs/apidoc')
}

asciidoctor {
    sourceDir = sourceDirGeneratedDocumentation
    outputDir = outputDirGeneratedDocumentation
    attributes = [
       doctype: 'book',
        toc: 'left',
        toclevels: '2',
        numbered: '',
        sectlinks: '',
        sectanchors: '',
    ]
}
```

and generate my documentation in HTML. I got a `html` folder with the following HTML files: `definition.html`, `overview.html`, `paths.html`.

But `paths.html` has one list of links to the all methods in the all controllers.

My question: How can I get links to REST controllers, which group links to methods of each REST controller?